# SPARQL: query for a complete list

Tags: sparql

I have such a query:

```
 CONSTRUCT {
    ?p a :IndContainer .
    ?p :contains ?ind .
} WHERE{
    :ClassContainer_1  :contains ?class .
    ?ind a ?class .
    BIND (IRI(...) AS ?p) .
}
```

An individual `ClassContainer_1` relates to some classes. I get this classes and try to find individuals for these classes. Then I try to create an `IndContainer` that should store found individuals (dots are used only for simplification). So, I want to:

1. Create individual of `IndContainer` only when individuals for all bindings of `?class` have been found;
2. Create individuals of `IndContainer` for all possible sets of individuals from `?ind` (i.e. when some of `?class` has a nuber of individuals).

Is it possible to create such a SPARQL query? Or it is necessary to use some rule engine?

EDIT (add illustration):
Positive example. Have:

```
test:ClassContainer_1
  rdf:type test:ClassContainer ;
  test:contains test:Type1 ;
  test:contains test:Type2 ;
.
test:Type1_1
  rdf:type test:Type1 ;
.
test:Type1_2
  rdf:type test:Type1 ;
.
test:Type2_1
  rdf:type test:Type2 ;
.
```

Want to receive:

```
test:IndContainer_1
  rdf:type test:IndContainer ;
  test:contains test:Type1_1 ;
  test:contains test:Type2_1 ;
.
test:IndContainer_2
  rdf:type test:IndContainer ;
  test:contains test:Type1_2 ;
  test:contains test:Type2_1 ;
.
```

Negative example: the same as positive except that there is no individuals of class `Type2` and so no individuals of `IndContainer` should be generated.

EDIT 2 (problem essence):
We may look at this problem from the perspective of combination composing. We have two positions (in my example) in each combination. The number of positions is determined by the number of classes each `ClassContainer` depends on. Each position must be filled in with one individual of a class that correspond to that position. So in my example first position must be filled with one individual of `Type1` class, the second - with `Type2` class (but the order does not matter). We have two individuals for the first class and one individual for the second class. To get the number of combinations we may use the rule of product from combinatorics - 2*1 = 2, i.e. {Type1_1,Type2_1} - is the first combination and {Type1_2,Type2_1} - is the second combination. For each combination it is necessary to generate `IndContainer` individual.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data that you have and the data that you would like your construct query to return.  It's not quite clear what you want.  I think it's possible using SPARQL, though.

Comment: Add illustrations for positive and negative cases.

Comment: Just a note, if you put "@<username>" in your comment, the person will get a notification.  I didn't get an alert about your comment, but I would have if you included "@JoshuaTaylor" in it.

Comment: What's the criteria for each of the two containers?  Why does container 1 contain "1_2" and "2_1", but container 2 contains "1_2" and "2_1"?  Should container 2 contain just "2_1" ?  It seems like you one one container per class;  is that right?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you for the reply and advise. My English is not good and that's why I might mislead. I try to clarify by adding more general explanation. So your problem understanding is not coincide with mine.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a "container" for each class that is contained in a "class container" that contains the individuals that belong to that class.  That's not too hard to do, as long as you can construct the IRI of the container from the IRI of the class.  Here's some sample data with two classes, A and B, and a few instances (some of just A, some of just B, and some of A and B):

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:container a :ClassContainer ;
           :contains :A, :B .

:w a :A .       # an :A
:x a :A .       # another :A
:y a :B .       # a :B
:z a :A, :B .   # both an :A and a :B
```

You query is already pretty close.  Here's one that works, along with its result:

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

construct {
  ?indContainer a :IndContainer ;
                :contains ?ind .
}
where {
  :container a :ClassContainer ;
             :contains ?class .
  ?ind a ?class .
  bind(IRI(concat(str(?class),"-container")) as ?indContainer)
}
```

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .

:B-container  a    :IndContainer ;
        :contains  :y , :z .

:A-container  a    :IndContainer ;
        :contains  :w , :x , :z .
```

Comment: In this case we should have 6 combinations: {w, y}, {w, z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {z, y}, {z, z}. Although I do not consider cases with multiple inheritance.

Comment: Ah, so given a list of classes X, Y, and Z, you're looking for all the members of the Cartesian product X x Y x Z.  E.g., if the list is Dog, Cat, where Dog = {d1, d2} and Cat = {c1, c2, c3}, you'd want 6 containers, right?  You'd want these: {d1,c1}, {d1, c2}, {d1, c3}, {d2,c1}, {d2, c2}, {d2, c3}?  That will be harder;  I'm not sure whether it's possible or not

Comment: Yes, that is right. I'm afraid it will be necessary to use some inference engine. I consider BasVisor and SWI prolog as a variant. Thank you anyway for your attention.

Comment: @user1576003 An inference engine really sounds like overkill.  Whatever language you're using, can't you just pull back the lists of individuals in the classes using the SPARQL query, and the construct the Cartesian product using that programming language?  Then you'd also have the option of computing them on demand, instead of transferring a big Cartesian product in a SPARQL result.

Comment: Yes, I can. I just thought I missed something about SPARQL that would help me to simplify the decision. Thanks.